# Как изобразить на блок-схеме результат функции с возвращаемым типом bool в качестве аргумента условного оператора?

Tags: c#, функции, условия, блок-схема

Дана функция с возвращаемым типом bool - `IsTrue()`. Возвращаемое значение функции управляет условным оператором. Подскажите, как лучше изобразить это на блок схеме.
Прилагается пример кода C#:

```
// C#

static bool IsTrue(int i)
{
    // на основе i возвращает булевое значение
}

static void PrintIt(int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (IsTrue(i))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

В качестве предположения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блок-схемы не подразумевают отображение синтаксического сахара языков программирования, поэтому для корректной записи решения этой задачи в виде блок-схемы:

1. Воспользоваться блоком процесса, в котором объявляется временная переменная bool, которая будет хранить результат функции. А после уже эту переменную сравнивать в блоке условия.
2. Написать функцию в блоке условия относительно синтаксиса c#: т.е. в блоке условия написать то, что написано в скобках конструкции if.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за объяснения